# java script if statement not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On client side, I have JSon data send to server

```
myJson = {
  request_type: 1,
  list_empty: false,
  data_list: []
};
```

send to server

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: self.serverURI,
  data: self.gen_data(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {},
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log(xhr);
  }
});
```

on the server

```
var m_bool = data.list_empty;
console.log("m_bool is printed: ", data.list_empty);

if (!m_bool) {
  console.log("m_bool = false");
}

if (m_bool) {
  console.log("m_bool = true");
}
```

The funny thing is server printed

```
m_bool = true
```

[image]

why if statements working?
I am using Node.js.

can anyone explain to me, thanks!

Comment: From the server, what does `console.log(data);` print? (edit your question with a snippet)

Comment: What is the output of `console.log("problem: ",data.list_empty);`?

Comment: console.log printed false.

Comment: What is `typeof m_bool`?

Comment: `list_empty` is `false` or `"false"`?

Comment: How are you sending data using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Please set

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

in your jQuery ajax call, and JSON.stringify your data before you send it will arrive at the server as a parse-able javascript object.

As you are using NodeJS it will arrive as a Javascript object, with correct booleans, not string.

If you leave out the content type attribute things get messed up.

Comment: could you give me complete JQuery? I am having error after adding "contentType: 'application/json'" to JQuery parameter.

Comment: What's the error? Check this doc once, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/...........   I could not fix that error before and it disappeared with JQuery without 'contenType'.  Now again, having this error. how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share complete error, it could be something else also. Setting up content type shouldn't throw error. 

Also check in network tab if request is being sent to server and getting failed after that ?

Comment: i decided to work with numbers, I tried parseInt(empty_list), which I set 1 or 0, so if works fine now. I struggled to fix that error, by no solution worked, i give up, decided to continue this path as I could. I really thankful for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing `m_bool = true`.

The reason for getting this printed is the `list_empty: false` would be received 
as string in the server side.

```
var s = "false";
if(!s) {
    console.log("S is false");} 
else { 
    console.log("S is true");
}
```

result of the above snippet is always "S is true".

Ensure that you are receiving it as JSON object on the server side, add the necessary headers `contentType: 'application/json'`

Answer (score -1):

In this case javascript checks that 'm_bool' should be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

```
if(m_bool)
```

But if you want to check boolean value you should write like:

```
if(m_bool === true)
```

This will only satisfy boolean true case.

Comment: `[...]should have any value or reference to any object,array variable etc.[...]` You should use the terms `truthy` and `falsy` here (MDN: [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy), [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/falsy)). Because `""` and `0` are values or _references_  to an object but they evaluate to `false`  if not used with `===`.

Comment: what is typeof m_bool. just write 'console.log(typeof moveTo);' it will tell you type